# The buttons should be visible when the user is done entering the value in the textfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have two textfields and two buttons and the button should not be visible till the user starts entering into the second textfield or the user has done entering in the second textfield.
Thanks,

---

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)secondFIB
{
    if (secondFIB.tag == 1703) {

        [self addPlusButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addButton1.png"] andFrameX:25 andFrameY:443 andFrameW:54 andFrameH:54];
        [self addNextButton:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scenariosButton_active_green.png"] andTitle:@"Next." andFrameX:475 andFrameY:443 andFrameW:234 andFrameH:54];
        /*UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        [addButton release];*/
    }
}
```

I did this but it doesn't work. Do I need to add this delegate method anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UITextFieldDelegates, and tag the textFields (button.tag = someNumber;

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == someNumberOftheOneYouWant) {
        // show Save Button
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        [addButton release];
    }
}
```

Or something like that... You'll have to set the button to nil when the cursor is in the other textfield.

> List of UITextFieldDelegates
>
> ## Managing Editing
>
> textFieldShouldBeginEditing:
>   textFieldDidBeginEditing:
>   textFieldShouldEndEditing:
>   textFieldDidEndEditing:
>
> ## Editing the Text Field’s Text –
>
> textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:
>   textFieldShouldClear:
>   textFieldShouldReturn: