# I need to know when a textfield is done being edited

Tags: textfield, cappuccino, objective-j

I have a class that contains several textfields. I need to know when one is done being edited and send the new information to one of my other objects.

This question seemed similar but in Objective C? [The buttons should be visible when the user is done entering the value in the textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5584833/793053)
Objective-j doesn't have the same functions.

Browsing the documentation I found several functions that seemed like they might be able to help such as, textDidEndEditing but didn't understand how to use it.  There are several more that sound related and I don't know what to use.

Summary: when the textfield is done being edited I need to perform another function. Also there are multiple textfields so I need to know which one is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controlTextDidEndEditing is the delegate method you should implement. Or you can just set the target/action of the textfield

Comment: controlTextDidEndEditing is not a method of the CPTextField class, at least, its not in the documentation.

Comment: How would I use setAction? My syntax is still really weak in objective-j. My closest guess would be:
[self setAction: setName:[self stringValue]];
I am sure this is wrong.

Comment: It is a delegate method, I dont know where the documentation is... if you use it, it will work. [textfield setAction:@selector(myMethod:)]